# How can we make precise the notion that a finite-dimensional vector space is not canonically isomorphic to its dual via category theory?

Tags: ct.category-theory, linear-algebra

There are quite a few questions both on this site and math.SE related to this topic as well as what we mean when we say "natural" or "canonical". For the purposes of this question, I'm going to consider canonical and natural to be synonyms, and use wikipedia's definition of an unnatural isomorphism:

> A particular map between particular objects may be called an unnatural isomorphism (or "this isomorphism is not natural") if the map cannot be extended to a natural transformation on the entire category.

From here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation

There's an excellent question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/622589/816960 which raises the issue that it seems to be an artefact of the definition of a natural transformation that there is no canonical isomorphism between $V$ and $V^*$, since the dual functor is contravariant. One of the answers suggests that the only way to resolve this is by showing that every dinatural transformation from the identity functor to the dual functor must be zero.

Personally I feel this doesn't get around the issue, because it seems to require us to redefine a canonical isomorphism between objects in a category as one which can be extended to a nontrivial dinatural transformation, and abandon the definition given above. Otherwise we're still left with a "definition not applicable"-based proof.

Another candidate is given here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/345148/175537 in which we change the definition of the dual functor.

> One way to get around this is by working instead with the core groupoid $\mathbf{Vect}_{core}$, consisting of vector spaces and invertible linear transformations, and defining $*:\mathbf{Vect}_{core} \to \mathbf{Vect}_{core}$ to be the functor taking $f:V \to W$ to $(f^{-1})^{\ast}: V^\ast \to W^\ast$, the linear adjoint of its inverse. Then one can ask whether the identity is naturally isomorphic to the covariant dual functor $\ast$. It is not.

But it seems like in both cases, we need a different definition of something to prove the nonexistence of a canonical isomorphism.

My questions are:

> Can we prove that any isomorphism between a finite-dimensional vector space and its dual is unnatural using the definition above, without appealing to the fact that the definition of a natural transformation doesn't allow comparisons of covariant functors with contravariant ones?

> Since I suspect the answer to the above is "no", does this mean the definition of "unnatural isomorphism" isn't quite right? what is the right definition of "canonical isomorphism" to use in order to do this properly with category-theoretic machinery?

Comment: It seems to me that Martin Brandenburg already deals with the identity not being isomorphic to the dual of the inverse of an isomorphism in his answer, no? Moreover, since $(f^{-1})^* = (f^*)^{-1}$, isn't a natural transformation from the identity to your functor a dinatural transformation from the identity to dualization (restricted to isomorphisms)?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you're addressing in your first question. Can you point out exactly where in Martin Brandenburg's answer this is dealt with?

Comment: I should clarify: the core groupoid idea is not mine, I'm quoting the MO answer linked above. I do think that is true (about it being a dinatural).

Comment: As far as the two examples of suggested solutions to this whole issue, I'm less interested in the specific merits of either of them than whether or not the usual definition of "unnatural isomorphism" or "canonical isomorphism" makes _any_ approach problematic.

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood your question at first. But now I'm not sure I get it. You say "cannot be extended to a natural transformation". But a natural transformation is something between functors. So are you really asking if the map cannot be extended into a triple (functor, functor, natural transformation)? Do you have any requirement on the functors? For example, between what categories...?

Comment: There is a notion of [dinatural transformation](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dinatural+transformation) which can allow one to talk about natural transformations between covariant and contravariant functors. I was sure this had come up one of the times this question had been asked here before...

Comment: @TimCampion It does come up (e.g. in the MSE question), and the result is that any dinatural transformation between the identity and the dual functors is zero.

Comment: @bxw This is not an idle question, because surely any morphism is a natural transformation between constant functors.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi That's a good point. In the context of this question, the functors are fixed. They are the identity functor $\mathbf{Vect} \to \mathbf{Vect}$ and the dual functor $\mathbf{Vect} \to \mathbf{Vect}$. In saying "cannot be extended..." I'm simply quoting the definition from wikipedia. I agree that there seems to be some missing constraint on the functors here. The constant functors is a good counterexample.

Comment: What do you call the dual functor? The contravariant one? Then there can't be a natural isomorphism by definition, or a dinatural isomorphism by the MSE answer you linked. The inverse of the dual, restricted to the core groupoid? Then it's also done in the MSE answer you've linked.

Comment: Yes, the contravariant one. "Then there can't be a natural isomorphism by definition", right, so this is the "definition not applicable" sort of proof that I mentioned above. So does this mean the definition of an unnatural isomorphism is limited in this respect? If I were to be as frank as possible, I'd say something like "this definition seems bad, why do we use it instead of an alternative, and are there any good alternatives?"

Comment: I don't see any future in attempting to define an "*unnatural isomorphism*".  Consider the **positive** question instead: any isomorphism (indeed homomorphism) $V\to V^*$ is a **structure**, otherwise written $\mu:V\otimes V\to K$.  Then $(V,\mu)$ and $(V,\mu')$ are *different* mathematical objects.

Comment: @PaulTaylor Maybe you're right. What would you propose as a definition of a "natural isomorphism". (between objects)? I don't think I understand the point you're trying to make here by pointing out that these are different objects. Sorry, could you please elaborate?

Comment: You could consider the category "Pair" of pairs $(V, \mu)$ where $V$ is a vector space and $\mu: V \otimes V \to K$ is a non-degenerate pairing (i.e. an isom $V \cong V^*$. A morphism is a map of vector spaces compatible with pairings. There is a forgetful functor from Pair to Vect which forgets $\mu$. You can ask: Does the forgetful functor admit a section? This would be a functorial choice of  isom $V \cong V^*$ for each $V$. The answer is no, there is no such section.

Comment: @ChrisSchommer-Pries There is, I think, one subtlety here, which relates to the OP: it is not obvious what does it mean for a map of vector spaces to be compatible with pairings. Say, the condition $\mu'(f(x),f(y))=\mu(x,y)$ somehow looks too strong: for example, it forces $f$ to be injective. It is like defining the category of metric spaces to have only isometries as morphisms, or to define the category of categories as having only full and faithful functors as morphisms.

Comment: @bxw: Why don't you accept the answer that answer to your question? please click the green check mark below the downvote triangle. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://mathoverflow.net/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 15):

Some people (including me) think that *"canonical"* should be synonymous with *"natural on isomorphisms"* or *"Functorial on isomorphisms"* (depending on if you are talking of a "canonical object" or a "canonical arrow"). Doing so solves the problem of variance in the definition.

To be clear, by "Functorial on isomorphism" I justs means that we have a functor $F:Core(C) \to D$ where $Core(C)$ is the subcategory of $C$ containing all objects but only isomorphisms as arrows. And by "Natural on isomorphisms", I'm asking for things that are natural transformation between such functors, i.e. that satisfies the naturality condition only with respect to isomorphisms.

If you look at the category of finite dimensional vector spaces and linear isomorphisms between them, here $V \mapsto V^*$ can be made into an actual (covariant) endofunctor of this category as you can fix the contravariance by inverting the morphisms, so that an invertible arrow $f:V \to W$ induces $(f^*)^{-1} : V^* \to W^*$.

And there you can concretely show that there is no natural isomorphism between this functor and the identity.

Indeed, chosing an isomorphism $V \simeq V^*$ gives you a non-degenerate bilinear form on $V$ and you can always find an automorphism of $V$ that does not preserves this bilinear form, which is exactly what the naturality on isomorphisms would mean! So at the end of they day, one recovers exactly the argument that [Paul Taylor](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/385955/how-can-we-make-precise-the-notion-that-a-finite-dimensional-vector-space-is-not#comment983821_385955) or [Chris Schommer-Pries](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/385955/how-can-we-make-precise-the-notion-that-a-finite-dimensional-vector-space-is-not#comment983873_385955) made in the comments, but starting with a concrete categorical definition of "canonical".

Comment: I think my answer is canonically isomorphic to yours. :)

Comment: I think they are actually quite different. You are looking at automorphism of k-Vect, I'm not. (But I also like your answer, in fact I'd love to see a situation where both leads to different conclusion)

Comment: I think an automorphism of k-Vect (which preserves the dual space functor) can be constructed from any automorphism $\alpha$ of a single vector space $V$. Precompose anything from $V$ with $\alpha^-1$; postcompose anything *to* $V$ with $\alpha$; similarly with $V^*$ and $\alpha^*$,$(\alpha^*)^{-1}$.

Comment: Here is an example where I think the two differs: Let $P$ be the category of posets with all supremum and infimum and all order preserving maps between them. Now the sentence "each object $X$ of P admits a canonical morphism $1 \to X$". Is true in my definition of caninical as I can send the unique element of $1$ to the top elements and this is functorial on isomorphisms, but it is not true for you definition as $P$ admit an automorphisms that "reverse the order relation" on each object which preserve $1$ but do not preserve my "canonical" choice.

Comment: OK, sorry, I see your point. You set things up so that we do not have the data of which relation is $\ge$ and which is $\le$ for each poset.

Comment: Although, as @GevaYashfe [points out](https://mathoverflow.net/a/385981), the statement that there is *always* an automorphism of $V$ that does not preserve a given non-degenerate bilinear form is very slightly false.

Comment: @SimonHenry Could you please give a precise definition for what you mean when you say "natural _on_ isomorphisms"? Does this mean we simply forget about any arrows which are not isomorphisms? Is there a meaningful analogue of this for talking about when isomorphisms between particular objects are natural as opposed to functors?

Comment: I'd like to get back to a drop-in replacement for the definition given at the beginning of the OP if it's possible.

Comment: Naturaliry is a condition (a commutative square) with respect to each morphism in the category. By 'natural on isomorphisms' I mean we only require this conditions for the arrow in the category that are isomorphisms. That is we are looking at natural transformations between the functors, but when the domain is restricted to the maximal subgroupoid.

Comment: @SimonHenry One more concern about terminology: how do we use the phrase "natural/functorial on isomorphisms"? Do we say call such a relation a "functorial isomorphism on isomorphisms"? Also, can you give an example of a canonical object?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the terminology question. The automorphism group of (for example) a set or a group is an example of something that is functorial on isomorphism without being functorial in general: If $X \simeq Y$ you get an isomorphism $Aut(X) \simeq Aut(Y)$, but for a general morphism $X \to Y$ you won't get a map $Aut(X) \to Aut(Y)$ nor a map $Aut(Y) \to Aut(X)$.

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand\kVect{k\text{-Vect}}$When people say ‘canonical’ what they mean in this context is something like ‘definable without parameters’ (i.e., without choosing bases; actually, without choosing anything at all). See for instance [the entry for “Definable Set” in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definable_set#Invariance_under_automorphisms). The important point is that canonical objects are invariant under automorphisms that preserve the relevant structure.

This means our isomorphism $V\to V^*$ should be invariant under all automorphisms of $\kVect$ that preserve the dualizing functor, considered as a contravariant functor from $\kVect$ to $\kVect$. This is not possible to obtain even for one finite-dimensional $V$. The reason is that with respect to some bases $B$, $C$ on $V$, $V^*$, a given isomorphism has the form of an identity matrix. But for any matrix $A$ representing an isomorphism $V\to V$, there is an automorphism of $\kVect$ which preserves the dual space functor and which transforms the representation of the given automorphism (with respect to the same bases $B$, $C$) to $A^T A^{-1}$. We can find a matrix $A$ for which this expression is different than $I$ (unless $\dim(V)=1$ or $\lvert k\rvert=2=\dim(V)$, as I learned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/622695/273756)). Thus the isomorphism $V \to V^*$ is not preserved by this automorphism.

Comment: Of course "unless $\dim(V) = 1$ or $\lvert k\rvert = 2 = \dim(V)$" should be "unless $\dim(V) \le 1$ …".  (You could also be cutesy and re-phrase as "$\dim(V) \le 1$ or $\lvert V\rvert = 4$".)